# DiscordJS: Setting url or appending parameter to url

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am using discordjs v13.

I have a command that sends a message to a specific channel. that message contains a button:

```
const button = new MessageButton()
      .setLabel("Go to Home")
      .setStyle("LINK")
      .setURL("https://home.com/");
```

My goal is to append a parameter containing the guildId and the userId. guildId is easy because when you send the message I already have access to know which Guild I am in.

But I will not know which user is clicking the button, till is clicked.

Any ideas?, Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why not wait to invoke `button.setURL()` until you have all the data, I don't think you have to set everything when creating a new MessageButton instance.

Comment: @Elitezen how can I grab the button once the message is sent?

Comment: One way would be to pass it to a function which will get all the data